# iOS load dynamic layer mask (i.e. layer mask is provided outside the code)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, layer

Situation: want to apply interesting photo frame to images, and the photo frame is implemented as layer mask, is it possible to dynamically build the layer mask by load a photo frame template outside of the obj-C code so that I can change the frame layer without ever touching the code?

the end result will be something like this. http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/106/Purple/9e/b9/9b/mzl.rdrrpcgr.320x480-75.jpg, except the photo edge/frame is dynamically loaded outside of the app, rather than built-into the app.

Ideally, would like to easily create a photo frame in photoshop as png file where the black pixel here will allow full transparency.. and then I can load this photo frame in the iOS app as the frame layer will allow the layer underneath to fully go through wherever the mask layer is black...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+ (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

Then you could use this method with a UIImage you load from a URL.

The URL could serve a different UIImage, or could take a parameter for which UIImageMask to load. Does this answer your question?